# Cannot execute Solr queries on non-Search nodes

Tags: solr, datastax

I'm using Datastax Enterprise. And I got the exception:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute Solr queries on non-Search nodes.
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
>       at com.example.cassandra.simple_client.App.main(App.java:98)

When I try to run the following:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint("104.236.160.56")
            .addContactPoint("104.236.160.96")
            .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build()))
            .build();

    Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", metadata.getClusterName());
    for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) 
        System.out.printf("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s; Dse version: %s; Cassandra version: %s\n", host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack(), host.getDseVersion(), host.getCassandraVersion());

    try {
        Session session = cluster.connect("rombie");
        ResultSet result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM rombie.force WHERE solr_query='{\"q\":\"point:[ 30 TO  *]\", \"sort\":\"point desc\"}'  LIMIT 50 ALLOW FILTERING");
        List<Row> list = result.all();
        for (Row row : list) 
            System.out.println(row.getString("force_tag"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2 nodes in the same datacenter and can see each other:

- 104.236.160.56: Cassandra
- 104.236.160.96: Solr

Note: It's working if I comment the Cassandra node: 104.236.160.56 OR using a normal query instead of a Solr query

Comment: Isn't the error telling you that if you're going to issue Solr queries, those can only be sent to the nodes that have Solr capability? So you'll have to leave the Cassandra node out for the Solr queries (as you'd otherwise hit a non-solr-query-capable node when load balancing)?

Comment: No. I have 2 datacenters: DC1 (2 cassandra nodes, 1 solr) and DC2(1 cassandra, 1 solr). I can add 3 nodes of DC1 in the above snippet, but not in case of DC2 :(